# jQuery - onChange Event won't fire on result site

Tags: jquery, onchange

i am experiencing an unusual bug and i cant figure out why.

I've got a page with a search mask. Depending on your selection, i get the available data via JSON from a php file and populate the select options with it. Its purpose is when you select a special offer, you're only listed the available offertypes and regions and not those were no offers are active.

Primary it works on every site of the page, using document.Ready function or the onchange="updateFunction" event.

Now when i do s search and display data (GET) which works fine, the onChange jQuery event doesn't seem to fire and i don't know why. Heres what ive got ... ( i did it with doc.ready function before)

```
 function updateDestination(){
    $('select#feld-urlaubsart').change(function() {
      var options = '';
      $.getJSON("database/checkoffers.php",{offertype: $(this).val()}, function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           options += '<option value="' + data[i].optionValue + '">' + data[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
        }
        $("select#feld-reiseziel").html(options);
       });
     });
    }

    function updateRegions(){
      $('select#feld-reiseziel').change(function() {
        var options = '';
        $.getJSON("database/checkregions.php",{country: $(this).val()}, function(data){
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           options += '<option value="' + data[i].optionValue + '">' + data[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
        }
        $("select#feld-region").html(options);
       });
      });
    }
```

Has anybody had the same issue beofre?

EDIT :

```
<select id="feld-urlaubsart" name="Urlaubsart" title="Bitte Angebotsart auswählen...">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Alle anzeigen</option>
<optgroup label="Golfurlaub mit Greenfees" title="Golfurlaub mit Greenfees">
<option value="1" title="Alle Greenfee Angebote">Alle Greenfee-Angebote</option>
<option value="2" title="Top-Angebote">Top-Angebote</option>
<option value="3" title="Golfurlaub mit 4 Tage Greenfee">Golfurlaub mit 4 Tage Greenfee</option>
<option value="4" title="Golfurlaub mit 5 Tage Greenfee">Golfurlaub mit 5 Tage Greenfee</option>
<option value="5" title="Golfurlaub mit 6 Tage Greenfee">Golfurlaub mit 6 Tage Greenfee</option>
<option value="6" title="Golfurlaub mit 7 Tage Greenfee">Golfurlaub mit 7 Tage Greenfee</option>
<option value="7" title="Golfurlaub mit 14 Tage Greenfee">Golfurlaub mit 14 Tage Greenfee</option>
<option value="8" title="Sonderangebote">Sonderangebote</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="Golfreisen mit Golfkurs" title="Golfreisen mit Golfkurs">
<option value="9" title="Alle Golfkurs-Angebote">Alle Golfkurs-Angebote</option>
<option value="10" title="Top-Angebote">Top-Angebote</option>
<option value="11" title="Golfreise mit Platzreifekurs">Golfreise mit Platzreifekurs</option>
<option value="12" title="Golfreise mit DGV-Platzreifekurs">Golfreise mit DGV-Platzreifekurs</option>
<option value="13" title="Golfreise mit Turnierreifekurs">Golfreise mit Turnierreifekurs</option>
<option value="14" title="Golfreise mit Handicapkurs">Golfreise mit Handicapkurs</option>
<option value="15" title="Golfreise mit Wochenend-Intensivkurs">Golfreise mit Wochenend-Intensivkurs</option>
<option value="16" title="Golfreise mit Turniergolfwoche">Golfreise mit Turniergolfwoche</option>
<option value="17" title="Professionell begleitete Golfreise">Professionell begleitete Golfreise</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

Reiseland<br />
<select id="feld-reiseziel" name="Reiseziel" title="Bitte Reiseland auswählen...">
<option value="Egal" selected="selected">Alle anzeigen</option>

<?php foreach ($data as $row) : ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['OfferCountry'] ; ?>" title="<?php echo $row['OfferCountry'] ; ?>"><?php echo $row['OfferCountry'] ; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<select id="feld-region" name="Region" title="Bitte Region auswählen...">
<option value="Egal" selected="selected">Alle anzeigen</option>
<?php foreach ($data as $row) : ?>
<?php if(!empty ($row['OfferRegion'])) :?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['OfferRegion'] ; ?>" title="<?php echo $row['OfferRegion'] ; ?>"><?php echo $row['OfferRegion'] ; ?></option>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

try delegating it to the document

```
 $(document).on('change','select#feld-urlaubsart',function(){
  .....
 });
```

and i don't think you need function to call the change event...remove the function `function updateDestination(){` and  `function updateRegions(){` unless you are calling it for some other reasons

Comment: still noch luck, i don't know what might be causing this. Is there a conflict because i am at a GET result and trying to "GET" data with JSON?

Comment: yep did, still not working (only on the detail site), otherwise it works perfectly fine - there must be something up with this

Comment: this is getting interesting... r u getting any error in detail site... check in youe console... may be some other javascript error is breaking this

Comment: nope, flawless. no js, css or doctype errors. i know its quire confusing - ive been struggling around for days and still can't figure it out